# Compile using GCC 6.3 on QT 5.7 Ubuntu

Tags: qt, ubuntu, gcc, c++14

I want to use c++14 features so I wanted to use the GCC 6.3 compiler.
I've done the list of commands found [here](https://gist.github.com/maxlevesque/5813df2fcee107c757f4)

Afterwards, I created a new kit, and used the newly installed xg++ compiler [here's the compiler description](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WUhnW.png) and added the following in my .pro `CONFIG += c++11 c++14`

Still the compiler doesn't recognize strings/cout/endl and can't use auto for automatic return type deduction. Also, the binary literals are not recognized.

what I am missing here?

Comment: The compiler or the IDE? You might get red underscores in creator because it doesn't support the syntax yet, but still get successful compilation.

Comment: it compiles and produces output while the binary literals are commented however there's still redlines under cout/endl/string. but once I put back the binary literal, I can't even build

Comment: Does this particular gcc version support that feature?

Comment: it supports c++14 by default now https://gcc.gnu.org/gcc-6/porting_to.html

Comment: Maybe you only need `CONFIG += c++14` ?

Comment: did not do any good, there's just this weird thing. when I first launch qt and the binary literal is commented, I build and Run without any red underscores, once I bring back the binary literal, red underscores come back ...

Comment: Do you get any error messages?

Comment: yes, I do get build errors if the binary literal is there

Comment: My point was if you want to get help, you should really include those errors in the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out that it's a bug in Qt Creator not switching to use the given compiler by providing its path in the kit. However, I executed the following steps from terminal:

```
// Update & Build Essentials & add ppa of the gcc & update again
$ sudo apt-get update
$ sudo apt-get install build-essential software-properties-common -y 
$ sudo add-apt-repository ppa:ubuntu-toolchain-r/test -y  // ppa of gcc 6.3
$ sudo apt-get update
$ sudo apt-get install gcc-snapshot -y
$ sudo apt-get update 

// Install the gcc and Add the gcc as an alternative
$ sudo apt-get install gcc-6 g++-6 -y
$ sudo update-alternatives --install /usr/bin/gcc gcc /usr/bin/gcc-6 60 --slave /usr/bin/g++ g++ /usr/bin/g++-6

// You can switch the gcc verions via
$ sudo update-alternatives --config gcc
```

and made an alternative to my existing GCC. Once I restored the default kit of Qt creator and set the default GCC to 6.3 instead of 4.8, I was able to run C++14 features with ease provided that
`CONFIG += c++14` is in the .pro.

Comment: Please edit your answer to include the steps in the link in case it ever goes dead.